# Checking syntax of strings - C#

Tags: c#, string, linq, string-comparison

I'm trying to find out how to analyze the syntax of a sentence in C#.
In my case I have a syntax which every sentence has to follow. 
The syntax looks like this:

> A 'B' is a 'C'.

Every sentence has to contain five words. The first word of my sentence has to be 'A', the third 'is' and the fourth 'a'.

Now I would like to examine a test sentence if it matches my syntax.

Test sentence:

> A Dog is no Cat.

In this example the test sentence would be wrong, because the fourth word is 'no' and not 'a' what it should be basend on the syntax.

I read about LINQ where I can query sentences that contain a specified set of words.

The code would look something like this:

```
//Notice the third sentence would have the correct syntax
string text = "A Dog is no Cat. My Dog is a Cat. A Dog is a Cat.";

//Splitting text into single sentences
string[] sentences = text.Split(new char[] { '.'});

//Defining the search terms
string[] wordToMatch ={"A", "is"};

//Find sentences that contain all terms I'm looking for
var sentenceQuery = from sentence in sentences
        let w = sentence.Split(new Char[] {'.'})
        where w.Distinct().Intersect(wordsToMatch).Count == wordsToMatch.Count()
        select sentence;
```

With this code I could check if the sentences contain my terms I'm looking for, but the problem is it's not checking the position of the words in the sentence.
Is there a way I could check the position as well or maybe a better way to check the syntax of a sentence with C#?

Comment: "intersect" doesn't say anything about where the words are in the list, so that won't do the job. What you want to do is split the input string and write a method that matches the pattern somehow -- either by hard coding `if (words[0] != "A") return false;` etc., or by giving it a set of rules -- maybe a list of objects like `{ int Index; string RequiredWord; }`. Your first sentence was alarming, but your actual requirement is fairly modest and reasonable. UPDATE if I had more sense, I'd have gone straight to Dmitry's regex idea. Your code can build regex strings too (then you have 3 problems)

Comment: Is "A Dog42 is a Cat17" a valid syntax?

Comment: @AleksAndreev In this case yes. I'm not trying to check if the sentence makes sense. Just trying to find out if the sentence contains the syntax I specified

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using *regular expressions*, something like this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string source = "A Dog is no Cat.";

bool result = Regex.IsMatch(source, @"^A\s+[A-Za-z0-9]+\s+is\s+a\s+[A-Za-z0-9]+\.$");
```

Pattern explanation:

```
 ^           - start of the string (anchor)
 A           - Letter A 
\s+          - one or more whitelines (spaces)
[A-Za-z0-9]+ - 1st word (can contain A..Z, a..z letters and 0..9 digits)
\s+          - one or more whitelines (spaces) 
 is          - is 
\s+          - one or more whitelines (spaces) 
 a           - a
\s+          - one or more whitelines (spaces)
[A-Za-z0-9]+ - 2nd word (can contain A..Z, a..z letters and 0..9 digits)
\.           - full stop 
 $           - end of the string (anchor)
```

You can slightly modify the code and obtain actual 1st and 2nd strings' values:

```
string source = "A Dog is a Cat."; // valid string

string pattern =
   @"^A\s+(?<First>[A-Za-z0-9]+)\s+is\s+a\s+(?<Second>[A-Za-z0-9]+)\.$";

var match = Regex.Match(source, pattern); 

if (match.Success) {
  string first = match.Groups["First"].Value;   // "Dog"
  string second = match.Groups["Second"].Value; // "Cat"

  ... 
}
```

Comment: How about: ' A 7 is a number'?

Comment: @sTrenat: in my current code the input `" A 7 is a number."` is *invalid*: it starts with a *space* (not `A`) and `7` is not a word. If such a string should be valid the pattern should be `@"^\s*A\s+[A-Za-z0-9]+\s+is\s+a\s+[A-Za-z0-9]+\.$"`

Comment: I knew that it won't, just wanted to get some example with numbers :) thanks

Comment: @sTrenat: I see in the comment that `"A Dog42 is a Cat17."` should be a valid input, I've edited the patterns (digits are added). Thank you!

Comment: I'm wondering why 7 won't work? Does [A-Za-z0-9] mean, the word has to start with a capital letter followed by lowercase letters which can also have numbers at the end? This is how I understand the specified pattern:  valid=Max12, invalid=max12, invalid=mAx12, invalid=12Max, invalid=7 ; Am I right?

Comment: @Joe Jonsman: a valid string with `7` is `"A 7 is a number."`, please, notice `.` (full stop at the end) and absence of leading and trailing spaces. `[A-Za-z0-9]` means any character in `A..Z`, `a..z`, `0..9` ranges. If you want "capital letter followed by lowercase letters which can also have numbers at the end" the pattern will be `[A-Z][a-z]*[0-9]*`

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression would work for this, and would be the most concise, but may not be the most readable solution.  Here is a simple method that will return true if the sentence is valid:

```
private bool IsSentenceValid(string sentence)
{
    // split the sentence into an array of words
    char[] splitOn = new char[] {' '};
    string[] words = sentence.ToLower().Split(splitOn); // make all chars lowercase for easy comparison

    // check for 5 words.
    if (words.Length != 5)
        return false;

    // check for required words
    if (words[0] != "a" || words[2] != "is" || words[3] != "a")
        return false;

    // if we got here, we're fine!
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to throw ideas. I would write three classes for this:

1. `SentenceManager`: which gets string as a sentence and has a public method `public string GetWord(word_index)`. for example `GetWord(3)` would return the 3rd word in the sentence that has been given to the class constructor.
2. `SentenceSyntax`: in this class, you can say how many words your sentence must have. what words must be known and you can set the index of those words too.
3. `SyntaxChecker`: this class gets a `SentenceSyntax` object and a `SentenceManager` object and has a function called `Check` which returns true if the syntax matches the sentence.

remember there can be thousands of ways to make something work. but there are some few ways to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely do this using Regex or something similar like [Dmitry has answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46006171/5671993)

Just for kicks, I wanted to do it your way. This is how I would do if I was going nuts :)

```
//Notice the third sentence would have the correct syntax
string text = "A Dog is no Cat.My Dog is a Cat.A Dog is a Cat.";

//Splitting text into single sentences
string[] sentences = text.Split(new char[] { '.' });

string[] wordsToMatch = { "A", "*", "is", "a", "*" };

var sentenceQuery = from sentence in sentences
                    let words = sentence.Split(' ')
                    where words.Length == wordsToMatch.Length && 
                          wordsToMatch.Zip(words, (f, s) => f == "*" || f == s).All(p => p)
                    select sentence;
```

Using this code, you can also get flexibility like cases insensitive comparison, and trim space around the word, etc - of course you will have to code for that